# How can I disable scaling of my sub calayer when resize it?

Tags: ios, calayer, scale

I have a sub CALayer with a image on it which is always changing size but I don't want to scale its content(the image) to fit the layer size. Instead, what I want is always keep the image size unchanged so that the image will be appeared bit by bit.

Is anyway to implement this effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should use a mask or set the contents gravity of the layer to `kCAGravityTopLeft` (see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html for more values).

The default value is `kCAGravityResize` which is why it's getting scaled.

Comment: The layer is not scaled any more. Thanks.

Comment: But it's still not the effect I want. My code is:

mylayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.bounds.size.width,h);

The h will change from 0 to full height of the image. But the bottom part is always showing first. It looks like the image slowly move from top to bottom. What I want is that the image stand still then slowly uncovered from top to bottom.

Comment: Hmmm, try a different gravity?

Comment: I tried kCAGravityBottom, but the whole image will always be shown even when the h is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't animate the layer's frame or change it.
CALayer has property `contentScale`

you might try something like this

```
let layer =  CALayer()
layer.frame = yourFrame
layer.contentsRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 1, width: 1, height: 0)
layer.contentsGravity = .top
let contentsRectAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contentsRect")
contentsRectAnimation.fromValue = layer.contentsRect
contentsRectAnimation.toValue = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
contentsRectAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero
contentsRectAnimation.duration = yourDuration
contentsRectAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
contentsRectAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
layer.add(contentsRectAnimation, forKey: "animation")
```

this will do the animation looks like your image in layer becomes visible from top to bottom

Comment: please aways explain what is in the link. as link will expire before your answers and users wont have clue about the answers.